# Маршрутизация linux от двух провайдеров

Tags: linux, маршрутизация

Здравствуйте! В фирме есть аппаратный маршрутизатор, работающий с 2-мя интернет-провайдерами. С него запросы посылаются на linux-машину. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы если запрос по порту 443 приходит через первого интернет-провайдера, на linux-машине редиректился бы на один порт, а если приходит на этот же порт 443 через второго интернет-провайдера, редиректился бы на другой порт на linux-машине? Аппаратный маршрутизатор такое не позволяет, а в linux destination IP один и тот же, вроде, получается для пакетов после аппаратного маршрутизатора, так что не понятно, по какому полю делать правило редиректа. Проблема в том, что после аппаратного маршрутизатора на стороне linux-роутера, видимо, нельзя понять, через какой провайдер шёл пакет.
Т.к. маршрутизатор подменяет destination ip (внешний ip маршрутизатора) на локальный ip linux-машины.

То есть в логах после команды:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables"
```

видим в поле dst не какой-то внешний (из двух) адрес маршрутизатора, а локальный адрес `192.168....` linux-машины, на которую пришёл пакет.
Итак, есть не 1 маршрутизатор на пути следования пакета из интернета, а два. Первый - аппаратный (tplink), с него пакеты попадают на второй, который работает на linux. У этого второго используется только одна сетевая карта (eth0) и одна подсеть. И нужно настроить этот второй на основании правила, основывающегося на определении канала, откуда пришёл запрос.

Понятно, что первый маршрутизатор можно убрать и всё сделать на linux, но задача стоит именно так, как описано.

Comment: Поддержка этого необходима на первом маршрутизаторе который получил запрос из вне. Если он аппаратный, то посмотрите еще раз его возможности, может можно его средствами как нибудь не совсем стандартно это сделать. Позже него вы пакеты уже никак не отличите в любом случае

Comment: Какая модель аппаратного маршрутизатора?

Comment: TL-R480T+ rev 5.1. В службе поддержки tplink сказали, что на уровне этого маршрутизатора такое сделать нельзя. Только если приобрести аналогичный TL-R480T+ с прошивкой версий 7,8 или 9. Поэтому пока предварительно решили всё сделать на linux, исключив аппаратный маршрутизатор. Большое спасибо всем за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Если вы пробрасываете порты на внешнем роутере к https серверу на linux и хотите отличить источник трафика, то можно сделать второй ip на сервере и пересылать трафик не на разные порты а на разные адреса. Тогда все что пришло на `ip1:443(isp1)` надо будет переслать на внутренний `ip_in_1:443`, а все что пришло на `ip2:443(isp2)` переслать на второй адрес сервера `ip_in_2:443`.

Хотя это станет невозможным если программа-сервер не может иметь настроек для разных интерфейсов.

Comment: Какая программа-сервер? Может роутер tplink?